# How to install QT on Windows in 2016

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, installation, wdk

This is a WiKi for people that find installing **QT for Visual Studio 2015 Edition** quite impossible. Why?

1. Because of the [**"LGPL Consultation Video"**](https://www.qt.io/qt-licensing-terms/) on the qt.io site, that may deter some people.
2. Because unfortunately QT MINGW is less useful - Less features, and slower build/executable.
3. Because of Visual Studio community edition 2015 **itself** - Which can be quite hard to install, with microsoft's online installer (many people get the same "missing packages" problem)
4. If installing Visual Studio 2015 is not hard enough. Installing WDK/Windows SDK to enable QT to compile/debug to windows is practically impossible without a very very important [hint](https://superuser.com/questions/1152478/windows-10-sdk-download-failes/1152556#1152556).

So, How do you install the best version of QT, for free, using the best installation option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Search for "Visual Studio community edition 2015 ISO" and download it. **You must avoid the online/offline installer as it simply does not work** If you have Windows 8/10 you just need to open the ISO by double clicking it and opening with "explorer" - **ISO mounting is now built-in in windows just like in Linux. So, that's a simple step**. The reason for downloading the ISO and not using the online/offline "installer" is that for some reason some critical packages are unavailable to download from the Microsoft site (many people reported the **"package missing"** problem.)
2. After downloading and mounting the ISO image install only the parts needed for QT (you might want to avoid the bloatware that comes with Visual Studio 2015. There's lots of it! You might need only one package the Visual C++ common tools itself.) I have found that installation of VS2015 can get stuck with a number of packages. **The installation might just get stuck**. Simple resolution: cancel the installer -> kill the installer from task manager -> restart the installer in "repair" mode -> ignore packages that won't install. I my case it required 3 packages that aren't required for QT windows development. I just ignored them and continued. The installation finally worked.
3. To enable QT to compile/debug to Windows you must also install Windows (10) SDK. The problem with both's installers is amazing on itself. Through [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1085) link I'v found out, that if you download and run the online installer sdksetup.exe under a folder that contains other files in it - the installer will fails to validate some of the packages it downloads. Again: **If you run the installer from a folder which isn't empty - your install will fail!** Also: It will fail with completely irrelevant error, so the chances you'll understand that you **have to install it from an empty folder (WTF?!)** are low. This bug has been verified by myself on multiple pc's, and by many other people on this planet...
4. Download the QT installer from [www.qt.io](http://www.qt.io)

   Select QT LGPL - **LGPL is NOT GPL - You can do whatever you want with LGPL Just as long you don't change the QT sources themselves, and acknoledge the user of the QT sources, so other people can access them too.** (THIS IS, BY THE WAY, NOT A LEGAL ADVICE!) If you want a legal advice, [you can check the one on QT site](https://www.qt.io/qt-licensing-terms/). I got to say that it does look intimidating to me. The acting, the yellow colors, ... etc. To me - their intentions are quite transparent.
5. Install QT Visual Studio 2015 64 bit edition.

If everything was installed alright - Qt should now be ready for work.
At least in Qt 5.7 the environment variables are automatically read/set from Visual Studio + Windows SDK, so you need not do anything else to start work.

Comment: Hi rubmz, you can mark your reply as answer, that will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier search your solution.